# Is there a posh-git equivalent for the Mac?

Tags: git, macos

I just found (and have fallen hard for) PowerShell with the posh-git module installed. I'd really like something similar on my Mac. Does such an equivalent exist?

Comment: Powershell became available for Mac probably since this question was asked, so the way to go now would be installing powershell and then posh-git via PowerShellGet per instructions https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are certainly ways to get features similar to what posh-git gives you.

For instance, [installing `bash-completion`](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) gives you the ability to `<tab>` complete Git commands.

Once you install `bash-completion`, you can add this to your `.bash_profile`:

`PS1='\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '`

This will include the current branch name in your prompt:

`user@computer-name current-folder (branch-name)$`

You can also add the following (found [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Git_quick_reference)) to your `.bash_profile` (before the PS1):

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
```

This will add flags after the branch name to show the repo's current state:

```
user@computer-name current-folder (branch-name *)$ #Repo has modified files
user@computer-name current-folder (branch-name +)$ #Repo has staged files
user@computer-name current-folder (branch-name %)$ #Repo has untracked files
```

You can also enable Git coloring with the following command:

`git config --global color.ui auto`

Comment: Intalled homebrew and bash-completition but the provided PS1 line generates `-sh: __git_ps1: command not found`

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel Are you loading the bash completion script in your `.bash_profile`? Make sure to follow the instructions `brew` gives after installing `bash-completion`. You can get the instructions again with `brew info bash-completion`.

Comment: Thanks @redhotvengeance . Yes I did add the required lines to /Users/{my-user}/.bash_profile and restarted terminal but `brew info bash-completion` still says "Not installed" :(

Comment: Actually, I ran `brew update`, then `brew install git bash-completion` (again), and now brew info bash-completion has more info. `__git_ps1() { : ; }` also doesn't throw errors now but I still don't see the git info :/ I did add the required lines to my .bash_profile and ran it with `source`. ideas?

Comment: This added details to the command line similar to posh-git but it did not apply any coloring to it

Comment: If you are getting the `-sh: __git_ps1: command not found` error, you need to download the [git-prompt.sh script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh). Read the instructions found in the script. An alternative source that helped me set this up can be found [here](https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/setting-up-git-prompt-step-by-step/).

Comment: The Git coloring command doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Do these also work for the zsh shell?

Answer (score 21):

[I ported the posh-git module as a shell script](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh).

As advised in the above post by `redhotvengeance`, you should install `bash-completion` to get tab-completion for Git commands.

Comment: Just setup your port on my machine. It's awesome thanks @lyze !

Comment: I feel like I can breathe again... thank you for this!

Comment: Wonderful! I've really been missing something like this on my Mac.

Comment: This also works well in Windows WSL

Comment: Works well for Raspberry Pi as well. Just amazing!