# Posh-hg equivalent for cygwin?

Tags: mercurial, cygwin

Is there a cygwin equivalent of [posh-hg](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/posh-hg) ?
 I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433165/is-there-a-posh-git-equivalent-for-the-mac) and there seem to be a lot of option available for git but sadly I couldn't find any for Mercurial.
What I am looking for is the branch and modification information that Posh-gh puts at the prompt, tab completion would be a nice additional touch but its not my main focus here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hg prompt](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/hg-prompt/) should work just fine in cygwin, as should the [bash completion script](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/tip/contrib/bash_completion) that ships with Mercurial.